How to install WinDBG offline on Windows Server 2019
I am wondering if it is possible to install new WinDBG on Windows Server 2019 offline.
I only want the new WinDbg, not the old WinDbg.
I have downloaded the .appinstaller file, fount the real download URL and then tried to install WinDBG from actual link:  https://windbg.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/prod/1-2402-24001-0/windbg.msixbundle
But, this error occurred and installation failed:
add-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CFF, To install this application you need either a Windows
developer license or a sideloading-enabled system.
Deployment of package Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2402.24001.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe with package origin Unknown failed because no
valid license or sideloading policy could be applied. A developer license
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233074) or enterprise sideloading configuration
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231020) may be required.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 3872f55a-e95b-0000-723d-73385be9da01 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 3872f55a-e95b-0000-723d-73385be9da01
At line:1 char:1
+ add-appxpackage .\windbg.msixbundle
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:\Users\...ndbg.msixbundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

Is there a solution to this problem?

Did you read the error message?  You are trying to side-load, so it should be no surprise that you need to enable side-loading first.

This has worked for me on winserver 2022, in admin powershell run: Add-AppxPackage -AppInstallerFile .\windbg.appinstaller

I have a workaround for you:
It can be used like a portable Software.
You can install it first on your normal win10/win11 machine. (with microsoft store or winget as described in your first link)
Then copy the whole directory from C:\Program files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_*
to your Server.
This should get you WinDbg on your offline 2019 system.

I found this script that someone wrote for an online install, but you can use the functionality for an offline install if you copy the msixbundle file to your offline server.
Download the msixbundle file:
Write-Host "Downloading windbg.appinstaller (XML manifest file)"
$AppInstallerUrl = "https://aka.ms/windbg/download"
$AppInstallerPath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "windbg.appinstaller"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $AppInstallerUrl -OutFile $AppInstallerPath

Write-Host "Parsing .appinstaller XML for windbg.msixbundle URL"
[xml]$AppInstallerXml = Get-Content -Path $AppInstallerPath
$NamespaceManager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($AppInstallerXml.NameTable)
$NamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018")
$BundleUrl = $AppInstallerXml.SelectSingleNode("//ns:MainBundle", $NamespaceManager).Uri

Write-Host "Downloading windbg.msixbundle (actual package file)"
$MsixBundlePath = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath "windbg.msixbundle"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $BundleUrl -OutFile $MsixBundlePath
$ProgressPreference = $DefaultProgressPreference

And then install it with Add-AppxPackage on the server:
Write-Host "Invoking Add-AppxPackage to install windbg.msixbundle"
    if ($PSEdition -eq 'Core') {
        $Command = "Add-AppxPackage -Path `"$MsixBundlePath`""
        Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-Command", $Command -Wait
    } else {
        Add-AppxPackage -Path $MsixBundlePath
    }

All code is taken from here:
https://gist.github.com/awakecoding/43f615e116fae64f721be7a98f8f60cf

Go to Setting => update and security => For developers, change from Microsoft store appss to Developer mode, then try again
